# Unable get data inside $when $done

Tags: jquery, json

OK, so Im trying to figure out why the same two pieces are not working. One works outside of my when/done statement but the one that i need to work is inside when/done. Can someone take a look and tell me what im doing wrong. Im able to get 2 out of 3 requests working just fine.

```
jQuery(function() { 

    var ConvExtID = 'jdv_electric';
    var ConvAPIKey = '369281456857b6910b0b8e0b1d7b046c';   
    var ConvAPISec= '%241%24SVUTmT1e%24hqQHTUvAFOoUuZ5bFVqle.';

    var NewConvData ='https://api.logmycalls.com/services/getCallDetails?criteria[external_ouid]='+ConvExtID+'&criteria[start_calldate]=2015-12-01&criteria[end_calldate]=2015-12-31&api_key='+ConvAPIKey+'&api_secret='+ConvAPISec+'&sort_by=id&sort_order=asc';
    var goaltotal = 'https://aspentouch.com/wp-content/plugins/CSAnalytics/lib/data/data-GoalValueTotals.php';
    var WeatherAPI = 'https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?q=27560&format=json&date=2015-12-01&enddate=2015-12-31&tp=24&key=5553de26af2e2c672d1042c05800d'

    //Creates Table for Weather Data

var channelHTML = ''
var DispositionAnswered = '';
var DispositionNoAnswer = '';
var TotalCallMin = 0;
var TotalCount = '';
var AvgCallDuration = '';
var ValueCallsSingle = '';
var ValueCalls = '';    
var ValueCallMinutes = 0;

    jQuery.when(
        jQuery.getJSON(WeatherAPI),
        jQuery.getJSON(goaltotal),
        jQuery.getJSON(NewConvData)
    ).done (function (data, data2, data3) {
        var data = data[0].data;
        console.log(data, data2, data3);
        var weatherHTML = '';
        var lookup = {};
        var weather = data.weather;
        for (var i = 0; i < weather.length; ++i) {
            var key = weather[i].date.replace(/-/g,'');
            lookup[key] = i;
            weatherHTML += '<li id="day'+[i]+'" class="day day-container"><div class="date">' + weather[i].date + '</div><div class="svg-icon"><img src="' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value + '" /></div><div class="data-wrap col2"><p class="data hi-temp"><span>' + weather[i].maxtempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p><p class="data lo-temp"><span>' + weather[i].mintempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p></div><p class="data desc">' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherDesc[0].value + '</p></li>';
        }
        jQuery('#weather_report').append(weatherHTML);
        jQuery.each(data2[0], function (i, item) {
            var day = jQuery("#day" + lookup[item.date]);
            day.append('<div class="content"><div class="content-conv-rate"><span class="goal-content">Goal Conversion Rate: </span><span class="goal-value">' + (+item.goalConversionRateAll).toFixed(2) + '%</span></div><div class="content-comp"><span class="goal-content">Goal Completions: </span><span class="goal-value">' + item.goalCompletionsAll + '</span></div><div class="content-value"><span class="goal-content">Goal Value:</span> <span class="goal-value">$' + item.goalvalueall + '</span></div></div>');
        })
        //I cant get this one to work
        jQuery.each(data3.results, function(i, value) {
            channelHTML += '<tr><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].calldate + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].tracking_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].disposition + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].duration + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].is_outbound + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].ouid + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].repeat_call + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].caller_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].ringto_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l"><audio src="' + data3.results[i].file_url + '" controls></audio></td></tr>';
            console.log(channelHTML);
        }); 
        //
        jQuery('.day-container').click(function() {
          jQuery(this).prev('.highlighter').find('.content').hide();
          jQuery(this).children('.content').animate({width: 'toggle'});
          jQuery(this).toggleClass('highlighter');
        });
        jQuery('#conv_table_one').append(channelHTML);
    });

    jQuery('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('selected').siblings('.anchor').removeClass('selected');
        jQuery('.goal-metrics').hide();
        jQuery('.chart-' + jQuery(this).data('target') + '-container').show();
    });
    jQuery('.showSingle').first().click();

    //this one works just fine
    jQuery.getJSON(NewConvData, function(data3) {
        jQuery.each(data3.results, function(i, value) {
            TotalCount = data3.results.length;

            var phoneNumbers = data3.results[i].caller_id;

            if ( !phoneNumbers.match(/^(\+?1)?(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$/) && data3.results[i].duration > 90 && data3.results[i].disposition === "ANSWERED") {
                ValueCalls+++1;
                ValueCallMinutes += parseFloat(data3.results[i].duration) / 60;
            }
            if (value.disposition === "ANSWERED") {DispositionAnswered++;}  
            if (value.disposition === "NO ANSWER") {DispositionNoAnswer++;}
            TotalCallMin += parseFloat(data3.results[i].duration) / 60;
            AvgCallDuration = TotalCallMin / TotalCount;

            jQuery.each(data3.results, function(i, value) {
                channelHTML += '<tr><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].calldate + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].tracking_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].disposition + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].duration + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].is_outbound + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].ouid + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].repeat_call + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].caller_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data3.results[i].ringto_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l"><audio src="' + data3.results[i].file_url + '" controls></audio></td></tr>';
            });
            jQuery('#TotalCount span').html(TotalCount);
            jQuery('#DispositionAnswered span').html(DispositionAnswered);
            jQuery('#DispositionNoAnswer span').html(DispositionNoAnswer);
            jQuery('#TotalCallMin span').html(TotalCallMin.toFixed(2));
            jQuery('#AvgCallDuration span').html(AvgCallDuration.toFixed(2));
            jQuery('#ValueCalls span').append(ValueCalls);
            jQuery('#ValueCallMinutes span').html(ValueCallMinutes.toFixed(2));
            jQuery('#conv_table_two').append(channelHTML);
        });     
    });     
    //End   
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="monthly-calendar">
    <ul id="weather_report" class="week ng-scope first">
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <table class="tg" id="conv_table_one" border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Call Date</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Tracking Number</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Disposition</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Duration</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">ID</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Is Outbound</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">OUID</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Repeat Call</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Caller ID</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Ring To Number</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Play Audio File</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="tg" id="conv_table_two" border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Call Date</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Tracking Number</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Disposition</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Duration</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">ID</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Is Outbound</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">OUID</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Repeat Call</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Caller ID</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Ring To Number</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">Play Audio File</th>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/javapatriot/k3cvb720/

Note: your browser may get hung up as it pulls in the data. SORRY!

Comment: What should this `jQuery.getJSON(GoalValueTotals)` do? `GoalValueTotals` is a json representing an array, not a url.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous - calling `jQuery('.totalinv').append(totalcost);jQuery('.totalleads').append(totalcompletions);jQuery('.perleadvalue').append(perleadvalue);` outside the done/success block will not get the expected results.  `totalcost` is also never defined in the code above

Comment: @TeoMor where do you make that assumption from? The variable declaration is not shown

Comment: Sorry, i updated the code to reflect the correct variables. Totalcost was replaced by totalinv and GoalValueTotals was replaced by GoalValueData

Comment: @charlietfl It is declared in the snippet the OP had posted. Note that he calls `jQuery.getJson(GoalValueData )` and `GoalValueData` is not a url as the `getJson` method requires (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: @TeoMor not sure if you can see edit history or not in the question (click on "edited 15 hours ago" .... but it actually wasn't defined at all in the first version of question. All the question edit history is viewable . Not trying to argue with you , but it was a bit of a red herring at the time and had no relevance

Comment: @charlietfl I've read the history; indeed, in the first version `GoalValueTotals` wasn't present, maybe I saw an edit version. Anyway, my point was that `jQuery.getJSON(GoalValueData)` is an invalid call and I didn't know what the OP expected to return. I didn't say this was the answer, just wanted to point the OP on a right track.

Comment: @TeoMor no problem ... point of my comment wasn't to stab at you either. Sometimes helps to point out things like that so question doesn't get side tracked away from main issue. Don't take any of it personally ... even if I am a pain in the ass sometimes ...lol

Comment: @charlietfl didn't take it personally :)

Comment: @javapatriot did you solve it?  It's failing because you have mixed-content (http/https) which the browser is blocking

Comment: Thanks but im confused because it is not blocking it when i call it outside of when/done, why would it be blocking it there?

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ don't know if you saw my last response but it works  when i call it outside of when/done, why would it be blocking it there?

Comment: You are probably on https - so when you call `jQuery.getJSON(NewConvData, function(data3) {` it works because `var NewConvData ='https` but `jQuery.when(
        jQuery.getJSON(WeatherAPI),
        jQuery.getJSON(goaltotal),
        jQuery.getJSON(NewConvData)` is a mix of `http/https`

Comment: Just look at the protocol of your urls `var NewConvData ='https://api.logmycalls.com'`(https) - `var goaltotal = 'http://dawsonselectric.com`(http)  - `var WeatherAPI = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com`(http)

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, i updated the JS to have all files come from https protocols but i still get the same result. Take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102013/discussion-between-javapatriot-and-).

Answer (score 0):

`$.when().done()` will be run after the code you have to update the elements.

Instead of :

```
jQuery.when(
    jQuery.getJSON(NewConvData),
    jQuery.getJSON(GoalValueTotals)
).done (function (data, data2) {
   // result processing code

});//end of `done()`

jQuery('.totalinv').append(totalcost);
jQuery('.totalleads').append(totalcompletions);
jQuery('.perleadvalue').append(perleadvalue);
```

Move the append code inside the callback

```
jQuery.when(
    jQuery.getJSON(NewConvData),
    jQuery.getJSON(GoalValueTotals)
).done (function (data, data2) {
   // result processing code

   jQuery('.totalinv').append(totalcost);
   jQuery('.totalleads').append(totalcompletions);
   jQuery('.perleadvalue').append(perleadvalue);


});//end of `done()`
```

Comment: sorry but that didnt work. Also because im calling the variables outside of $.when().done() i should be able to run my append code outside of it as well.

Comment: if those functions are dependent on returned data you need to run them inside done also. `$.getJSON` is asynchronous

Comment: Gotcha, i updated the code to reflect this, i'm still having the same error though.

Comment: Can't help with error , no idea what is in stack trace where it gets thrown. Need to use browser dev tools to sort that out